# insert command of sql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
class insertdata extends insert implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try{

                    stno=t1.getText();
                    s_name=t2.getText();
                    s_email=t3.getText();
                    bno=t4.getText();
                    s_no=Integer.parseInt(stno);
                    b_no=Integer.parseInt(bno);}
                    catch(Exception e1){System.out.println(e1);}
                System.out.println(s_name);
                try{  
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Library","root","");  


                    String query = " insert into Students (s_no,s_name, b_no, s_email)"
                            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                          // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                          preparedStmt.setInt (1, s_no);
                          preparedStmt.setString (2, s_name);
                          preparedStmt.setInt  (3, b_no);
                          preparedStmt.setString(4, s_email);
                          preparedStmt.execute();


                    con.close();  
                }catch(Exception e1){ System.out.println(e1);}
            }
        }

        insertdata i=new insertdata();
        ba1.addActionListener(i);


    }
}
```

I have connected this java code with database Library and want to take values from user and save them in Students. but values saved in table Students after running this code are null and not the values entered by user. can anyone help me?? thanks in advance

Comment: Use a debugger and find out what is happened

Comment: you need the commit clause

Comment: did you try debug the code ? and check your variables

Comment: This bug has absolutely nothing to do with commit! If you don't commit a transaction, there's nothing in the db, and not a row full of nulls! As Jens mentioned, debug your code. Set a breakpoint at "catch(Exception e1){System.out.println(e1);}" and inspect the values for your variables.

Comment: That code is fine. Therefore s_name and s_email do not have the values that you believe but are null.

Comment: @StefanBeike auto commit is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should use 'preparedStmt.executeUpdate()' instead of 'preparedStmt.execute()'.

Answer (score -1):

after removing extends insert code is working fine

class insertdata implements ActionListener{ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)